# Sample size required to estimate population proportion with given precision

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, parameter-estimation

> It plans to conduct a study on the percentage of homeowners who have at least two TVs.
>
> What should be the sample size if we want to ensure that $95\%$ of estimation error is less than $0.01$?

*The original French text version:*

[image: The original]

i have some old exercise in paper of  Inferential Statistics, i'm trying to rewrite it with solution in latex to stock it in my googledrive but i don't have any idea because It's been a long time since I studied. Any help would be much appreciated

as Mr Paul

we want to calculate
$$\operatorname{A confidence interval}=\overline{X}\pm E\quad  \textrm{with}\quad E={{Z}_{\tfrac{\alpha }{2}}}\sqrt{\dfrac{P(1-P)}{n}}$$
or
$${Z}_{\tfrac{\alpha }{2}}=1.98\quad P = 0.5 \quad n=?$$
Then
$$2\times 1.98\times \sqrt{\frac{0.5\left(1-0.5\right)}{n}}=0.01$$

Thus the sample size should be equal $9801$

Am I right ?

Answer (score 3):

A confidence interval for the values of a random variable (like the % of homeowners in a sample who own at least 2 TV's) is of the form

$$\overline{X}\pm E$$

where $\overline{X}$ is the sample mean and E is the error. The form of E depends on the type of variable $X$ you are looking at but in your case, for a large sample of values n, it is given by

$$E={{Z}_{\tfrac{\alpha }{2}}}\sqrt{\dfrac{P(1-P)}{n}}$$

Here $P$ is an estimate of the mean $\%$ of homeowners who own at least $2$ TV's (this interval is called the "*confidence interval for proportions*" in most stats books). This might be done by taking a sample of homeowners but if no sample is taken the best estimate you have is $50\%$ or $P = 0.5$. The number ${Z}_{\tfrac{\alpha }{2}}$ can be looked up in a table and has the value $1.98$ for $\frac{\alpha}{2}=0.05$ or $5\%$ significance.
You now want to solve

$$0.01=1.98\sqrt{\dfrac{{{0.5}^{2}}}{n}}$$

for $n$.

Comment: Thanks so much do you have any reference books which have the same exercise with solutions

Comment: At a basic level (without worrying too much about why certain things are as they are) any book with "Business Statistics" or "Statistics for Engineers/Scientists" will do. One on my shelf is Statistics Explained by J. Parry Lewis & Alasdair Traill (Addison Wesley) which looks OK. How do you centre text in an answer by the way?!

Comment: by :   `\begin{align} text you want to center  \end{align} ` or by `$$`signs